# Sampling from unknown, but constrained, distribution

Tags: sampling, simulation, rejection-sampling

I'm trying to simulate a measurement (in astrophysics, so please excuse my weak grasp of statistical notation). The distribution I want sample from is for two correlated quantities $m$ and $w$, call it $f(m, w)$. The quantities are bounded in the intervals $m\in[m_{\rm min},m_{\rm max})$ and $w\in[w_{\rm min},w_{\rm max})$. I don't know the distribution, but I know some of its properties. I know the cumulative distribution marginalised along both axes, i.e. $g(m)$ and $h(w)$ are known functions:

$$\int_{w_{\rm min}}^{w_{\rm max}}\int_{m_{\rm min}}^mf(m, w)\,{\rm d}m{\,\rm d}w = g(m)$$
$$\int_{w_{\rm min}}^{w}\int_{m_{\rm min}}^{m_{\rm max}}f(m, w)\,{\rm d}m{\,\rm d}w = h(w)$$

I also know the probability density for $w$ at a given $m$, call it $p(w|m)$. How can I generate a sample consistent with these constraints? I suspect this may not be possible for all $g(m)$, $h(w)$ and $p(w|m)$, is it possible to check whether a solution exists?

---

Wanted to keep the specific details of my problem separate, but here they are in case it can help:

$$g(m)=\frac{-\Gamma\left(a_m+2,\frac{m}{m_0}\right)+\Gamma\left(a_m+2,\frac{m_{\rm min}}{m_0}\right)}{-\Gamma\left(a_m+2,\frac{m_{\rm max}}{m_0}\right)+\Gamma\left(a_m+2,\frac{m_{\rm min}}{m_0}\right)}$$

$$h(w)=\frac{-\Gamma\left(\frac{a_w+1}{b_w},\left(\frac{w}{w_0}\right)^{b_w}\right)+\Gamma\left(\frac{a_w+1}{b_w},\left(\frac{w_{\rm min}}{w_0}\right)^{b_w}\right)}{-\Gamma\left(\frac{a_w+1}{b_w},\left(\frac{w_{\rm max}}{w_0}\right)^{b_w}\right)+\Gamma\left(\frac{a_w+1}{b_w},\left(\frac{w_{\rm min}}{w_0}\right)^{b_w}\right)}$$

where $a_m$, $a_w$, $b_w$, $m_0$ and $w_0$ are known constants and $\Gamma$ is the (upper) incomplete gamma function.

$$p(w|m)=\frac{1}{\sigma(M)}\frac{e^{-\left(z(M,W)+e^{-z(M,W)}\right)}}{e^{-e^{-z_{\rm min}}}-e^{-e^{-z_{\rm max}}}}$$

where:

$z(M,W)=(\mu(M)-W)/\sigma(M)$,

$z_{\rm min}=z(M,W_{\rm min})$, and $z_{\rm max}=z(M,W_{\rm max})$,

$\mu(M)=a_\mu M-b_\mu$,

$\sigma(M)=-a_\sigma M + b_\sigma$

$M=\log_{10}m$

$W=\log_{10}w$, $W_{\rm min}=\log_{10}w_{\rm min}$, and $W_{\rm max}=\log_{10}w_{\rm max}$

Finally, $a_\mu$, $b_\mu$, $a_\sigma$ and $b_\sigma$ are known constants. Quite a mess!

Comment: If you know $p(w \mid m)$ and $g(m)$ then use $f(w,m)=p(w \mid m)\cdot g(m)$

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen: the functions $g(\cdot)$ and $h(\cdot)$ are cdfs.

Comment: It sounds like $g(\cdot)$ can be inverted as a truncated Gamma distribution and hence $g^{-1}(U)$ be used as a generator for this marginal.

Comment: @Xi'an Yes, but that doesn't enforce $h(w)$, right? On further reflection I'm becoming convinced that the specific constraints I have cannot be simultaneously satisfied (but there may specific combinations of $g(m)$, $h(w)$, $p(w|m)$ for which it is possible). Would still be very interested in how to go about proving the impossibility, if this is indeed the case.

Comment: If they are compatible, one should get$$h^\prime(w)=\int p(w|m)g^\prime(m)\,\text dm$$

Comment: @Xi'an That's certainly not going to hold for my specific problem. Very useful to know. Should make it an answer so I can upvote it, etc...